# How to POST with MongoTemplate to a document with Kotlin?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, mongotemplate

I'm currently using MongoTemplate to POST the contents of a class using the mongoTemplate.save method.

However, I noticed that this ONLY posts to a database / document with the same name that was set in the MongoTemplate constructor.

That is, if I have -

```
val mongoTemplate = MongoTemplate(MongoClient(/*...uri...*/), "DatabaseA")
```

What happens is that I then have a Database/Document titled "DatabaseA.DatabaseA"

However, I wish to post to a different document WITHIN DatabaseA, that is DatabaseA.DocumentB and so on.

I looked online but found no reference how to do that. is it possible to do so with MongoTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whelp, looking over it seems you can't. It seems the above pattern is by design with no way to override it.